# Ubuntu 13.04 completely frozen

Tags: 13.04

I currently use Ubuntu 13.04 on LG X110 notebook
After last updating (on 28th August 2013) software doesn't work. It suddenly stops while I'm using it. Hardware still runs: I know because of the noise, but noise it has during doing no operation. Software doesn't work at all: desktop is frozen, mouse is blocked, any keyboard command gives no result. 
I already uninstalled Xubuntu, in case there was some bug with it, but it just doesn't matter.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If it is happening to you after installing a different operating system it is probably a hardware problem.

Sounds like you could have a problem with your ram.
When you turn on your computer and grub loads, run memtest+ and let it run overnight. If it gives any errors then your ram is the issue and you should replace it.

Comment: Thanks. (I use Ubuntu on this notebook since July 2010, however). I installed grub-customizer to have memtest86, because I don't have it at all. but now it doesn't allow me to run grub-customizer. do you know which command may I insert to run the programme via terminal ?

Comment: So memtest runs without the operating system, so that's why it has to start at the grub loader stage. Another option is to download the program, burn it to a cd, then boot from CD. I've had to do that before

Comment: Thanks for answering. I noticed another point: laptop works quite good with at most 70% RAM; suddenly a new process, named zeitgeist-fts, appears and it uses 390-430 MB of RAM and computer stops! Do you know if is it this zeitgeist usefull for something ? (I don't think so because it starts to run after several minutes, not at turning-on) and How could I delete it ?

Comment: Ok, so you have probably run out of RAM and that's why its frozen. You don't really need zeitgeist so removing it should sort you out. See here: http://linuxaria.com/howto/how-to-remove-zeitgeist-in-ubuntu-and-why?lang=en

Comment: I removed zeitgeist (almost all packages) but I remained with no desktop and with no Gedit programme (a part of the -useless- left side bar - I already have Docky). So I installed again zeitgeist packages; but I am still without desktop! Please, what can I do ?

Comment: Ok, Nautilus was missing: I installed it; but I am still without upside bar (the black bar) and some bug for windows because that bar is missing I suppose...

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on the link? No one there has complained that they have deleted their desktop